# Minecraft Maximum Window

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, so I have this recording system that only works at the maximum screen for Minecraft. I was trying to record a video on fullscreen but my cousin messed with my Minecraft and screwed everything up. I just want a specific answer as to how to fix this!

Comment: You want to put Minecraft into fullscreen? Isn't that just '`F11`'?

Answer (score 3):

You can enter Fullscreen Mode (I assume you are referring to that) by

- pressing the key that you assigned to that toggles Fullscreen Mode (<kbd>F11</kbd> by default, some computers require <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>); or
- go into `Options` menu -> `Video Settings` -> press`Fullscreen`; or
- go into the `options.txt` file directly and change the `fullscreen` option to `true`.